# Regex in a list in terraform

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to regex a specific variable in a list, specifically in the tags of an `aws_instance` in terraform. It looks like this:

```
variable "string"  { default = "Foo" }
variable "id"  { default = "https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/item-v1.2/item-item2-v1.2.gz" }
variable "id2" { default = "456" }

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-123456"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "${join(".", compact(list(var.string, var.id, var.id2, "lorem-ipsum")))}"
  }
}
```

Would I be able to apply a regex on `variable.id` in that list, specifically

```
${replace(variable.id, "/.*-(.*)/.*/", "$1")}
```

So the output would be something like

```
tags = foo, v1.2, 456, lorem ipsum
```

The regex already works, I just have no idea how to put it in a list like that. How would I go about in doing it? Thank you!

Comment: Is it TF 0.11? If not, which version do you use?

Comment: It's 0.14.4 @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using TF 0.14.4, you can do the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-123456"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = join(".", compact(list(
                var.string,
                replace(var.id, "/.*-(.*)/.*/", "$1"),
                var.id2,
                "LOREM-ipsum")))
  }
}
```

The above gives:

```
Foo.v1.2.456.LOREM-ipsum
```

Or simpler:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-123456"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = join(".", [
                var.string,
                replace(var.id, "/.*-(.*)/.*/", "$1"),
                var.id2,
                "LOREM-ipsum"])
  }
}
```